Angular 17 Proxy config loads localhost
I am new in angular trying to use proxy.conf in to access firebse auth endpoint but it hits the localhost instead of the end point mentioned in proxy.conf.
below is the ERROR:
Network Tab: Request URL:
http://localhost:4200/api/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBM7Aki_Onuw0OJCFqY5HMK5wIIzvWHOGg
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:4200
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
console log: auth.component.ts:22
POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBM7Aki_Onuw0OJCFqY5HMK5wIIzvWHOGg 404 (Not Found)`
`auth.component.ts:22 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBM7Aki_Onuw0OJCFqY5HMK5wIIzvWHOGg', ok: false, …}
proxy.conf.json file where i mentioned the endpoint


{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
     },
     "changeOrigin": true
  }
}



angular.json file where i define proxy.conf.json:


 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/user-registration",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget":"User-Registration:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "User-Registration:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "User-Registration:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "User-Registration:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>



below is the function where i am trying to access the firebase endpoint
signup(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>('/api/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[KEY]',
            {
                email: email,
                password: password,
                returnSecureToken: true
            });
    }

